# Hiper vinculos personalizados en control Richtextbox WINFORMS

Tags: c#, windows-forms, enlace, rtf, richtextbox

Estoy diseñando un procesador de texto, mi misión principal es lograr emular la funcionalidad de un `IntelliSense` pero usado para otro fin. Para componerlo uso un control `Datagridview` y un `Richtextbox`.

La funcion del pseudointellisense aparece cuando abro un corchete ( '[' ) y termina si clickeo en algunos de los datos filtrados en el datagridview o si cierro el corchete ( ']' ). Lo que necesito es crear un hipervinculo una vez clickee en alguna de las opciones que se me muestran y que al hacer llave a una función.

¿Cual es el problema de todo esto?.
El control `richtextbox` tiene palabras claves para crear enlaces pero estos solo funcionan si lo que contiene tiene formato de enlace como por ejemplo ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que necesito hacer es algo como esto

[Poder introducir el texto que yo quiera y que sea un hipervinculo](https://www.google.com)

Luego encontré el lenguaje RTF propio del control (Rich Text Format)
No lo conocía y por lo que leí este funciona como una especie de HTML. Al intentar implementarlo tampoco me termino sirviendo parte mia por carecer de conocimientos de su uso y por la forma en que tengo codificado el programa.

> Funcion que se llama cuando se escribe sobre el Richtextbox

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (verificarDeCorchete)
        {
            char[] corchetes = new char[] { '[', ']' };
            string where_buscador = VALOR_WHERE.TrimStart(corchetes);
            textBox3.Text = where_buscador;

            dt_gv.DataSource = connections.conn_database.SELECT($"SELECT * FROM tabla_de_nombres WHERE Descripcion LIKE '{textBox3.Text}%'");
            if (dt_gv.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //Muestra el intellicense
                dt_gv.Visible = true;

                //Este codigo sirve para seguirle el rastro al carrete y 
                //asi el intellicense este donde se pueda ver
                var o = Utility.GetCaretPoint(richTextBox1);
                xpos = o.X;
                ypos = o.Y;
                textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(xpos + "," + ypos);
                dt_gv.BringToFront();
                dt_gv.Location = new Point(xpos + 15, ypos + 30);
                richTextBox1.Focus();

            }
            else
            {
                dt_gv.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

> Funcion que valida que caracter se esta ingresando (para saber cuando esta abriendo y cerrando corchetes)

```
 private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            //Si es inicio de corchete activa el boleano
            if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "[")
            {
                verificarDeCorchete = true;
            }
            //Si es el final de corchete lo desactiva
            else if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "]")
            {
                verificarDeCorchete = false;
            }

            //Si el boleano esta activado o es el final de un corchete entra al if
            //Se agrego la condicion del corchete cerrado para que lo pinte de rojo tambien.
            if (verificarDeCorchete || e.KeyChar.ToString() == "]")
            {
                //Desactiva la vista del "Intellicense"
                dt_gv.Visible = false;

                //Pinta de rojo los colores dentro
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;

                /*Si el valor del string es nulo agrega el caracter 
                 * (esto pasa solo si es el primer caracter)*/
                if (VALOR_WHERE == null)
                {
                    VALOR_WHERE = e.KeyChar.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Si el string es distinto a 0
                    if (VALOR_WHERE.Length != 0)
                    {
                        /*Esta condicion sirve para los backspace
                         al tocar esta tecla el programa lo leia como un caracter
                         (aunque no lo fuera) y rompia la logica y dejaba un string
                         mal escrito. Al hacer esto se borra el caracter (como pasa exactamente)*/
                        if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "\b")
                        {
                            VALOR_WHERE = VALOR_WHERE.Remove(VALOR_WHERE.Length - 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            VALOR_WHERE = VALOR_WHERE.Replace(VALOR_WHERE, VALOR_WHERE + e.KeyChar);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Si es 0 copia el valor como pasa cuando es nulo.
                        VALOR_WHERE = e.KeyChar.ToString();
                    }
                }
                //Copia el valor en el textbox para pruebas. esto tiene que borrarse.
                textBox1.Text = VALOR_WHERE;
            }
            else
            {
                //Cambia el color de la fuente si no es una busqueda especial.
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
                //Lo lleva a vacio para volver a usarse en otro momento.-
                VALOR_WHERE = "";
            }
        }
```

> Con esta funcion al clickear en alguna de las opciones del datagridview esta lo pega en el richtextbox. En esta parte se deberia implementar el codigo que crea el enlace. (En hipervinculo lo necesito para llamar a una funcion, no es para ingresar a una pagina web.)

```
 private void dt_gv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dt_gv.Visible = false;
        verificarDeCorchete = false;
        //Obtiene la posicion del carrete en ese momento
        int caret_position = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(Utility.GetCaretPoint(richTextBox1));
        int start_index = caret_position - VALOR_WHERE.Length;
        int length = VALOR_WHERE.Length;

        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Remove(start_index, length);

        string valor_seleccionado = dt_gv.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();

        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(start_index, " " + valor_seleccionado + " ");

        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace("[", "");
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace("]", "");

        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = start_index + length + valor_seleccionado.Length;
    }
```

> Al abrir corchetes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Al clickear en alguna opción (Esto debería ser un hiper vinculo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea?

Comment: Amigo, encontré una pregunta similar en la web en [inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12306071/11335797) sin embargo, creo que puede servir dado que crea una función para añadir hipervínculos.

Comment: El problema es que para usar la propiedad `Document` del control `Richtextbox` se debe usar WPF

Comment: Ahh cierto, mis disculpas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución a tu pregunta:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox

Quien publicó dicho post parece que modificó el archivo que define la propiedad DetectUrls del RichTextBox para que puedas hacer que cualquier palabra sea un "hipervinculo" capaz de disparar un evento al recibir un click.

Si descargas el código fuente de su proyecto y utilizas su RichTextBox "extendido", podrás avanzar.

Comment: A 9 minutos de que la recompensa expire me llega la notificació, agradezco mucho tu ayuda! 
Feliz año.

Comment: Gracias! Qué bueno que te funcionó, feliz año

Answer (score 0):

Como posible solución puedes crear un LinkLabel con el texto que quieras y situarlo justo encima de donde querias situar el hipervínculo original. A continuación expongo el código aproximado a seguir.

Tras finalizar tu código en el evento `dt_gv_CellClick` primero necesitamos la localización del texto que acabamos de insertar. La sacamos de la siguiente manera:

```
int index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(richTextBox1.Text);
Point textBoxLocation = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(index);
Point windowsLocation = new Point(richTextBox1.Location.X + textBoxLocation.X, richTextBox1.Location.Y + textBoxLocation.Y);
```

Una vez con esto, habría que crear el LinkLabel, ajustarlo a la fuente del RitchTextBox y ubicarlo justo encima del texto que acabas de añadir. Después controlaremos su método `LinkClicked` que es el que se ejecutará al hacer click sobre el `LinkLabel`:

```
LinkLabel linklabel = new LinkLabel();
linklabel.AutoSize = true;
linklabel.Font = richTextBox1.Font;
linklabel.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
linklabel.Location = new Point(windowsLocation.X + 1, windowsLocation.Y + 2);
linklabel.Text = richTextBox1.Text;

formPadre.Controls.Add(linklabel);
linklabel.BringToFront();

linklabel.LinkClicked += linklabel_LinkClicked;
```

Tras esto añadiremos el código del método `LinkClicked`, aquí en lugar de llamar a un proceso para que se abra el vínculo, puedes añadir la llamada a la función que dices:

```
void linklabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    // LLamada a tufuncion();
}
```

Como nota final decir que si, esta solución es un poco "chapuza" y no es la óptima, de hecho habría que controlar también que no haya mas texto repetido para localizar bien la posición. Asegurarse que el LinkLabel lo añades al control padre del RichTextBox correcto, etc. Pero creo que es una solución que puede funcionar bien, no sobrecarga en términos de rendimiento y da el resultado que estás buscando.

Comment: Agradezco tu ayuda Nacher el problema es que al ser un procesador de texto este de seguro va a tener que borrarse, re formatearse y agregar texto constantemente. Es decir, no sera estático. De echo esta idea la extraje de un sitio y la use pero no me termino convenciendo por lo antes dicho.

Comment: Quizas podrías conseguir algo si cada texto que quieras convertir lo guardas en un listado de strings, e iterar sobre dicho listado tras cada pulsación de tecla para destruir los LinkLabel y volver a generarlos donde corresponda. Pero entiendo que quizas ya es rizar demasiado el rizo.

Comment: Lo que estoy pensando en hacer es terminar usando el lenguaje RTF. Aunque por alguna razon al clickear sobre el link este no dispara la funcion de LinkClicked.